# Ruby On Rails Heroku Postgres databases SSL Connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ssl, heroku

I received an email from Heroku saying that I may have a postgres database that is not connecting via ssl.  Heroku is going to start requiring ssl and will begin brownout tests in February 2018 to determine definitively if your app is OK.  From what I understand, the Rails Postgres driver will try ssl first by default.

I can't find a thing on how to confirm this.

Heroku offers a [document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-ssl-brownouts#how-can-i-determine-whether-my-database-is-running-on-legacy-infrastucture) that has information about postgres, ssl and brownouts, but it doesn't say how to test ahead of time.  Node and Java apps are most likely to be affected.

I don't want to have my app go down for a few minutes.  How do I confirm that my connection will be OK ahead of the brownout?

Comment: Are you in a position to upgrade the database (and in doing so switch away from their "legacy" infrastructure)? If you are able to do so then once on the new (PGX) infrastructure you should not be at risk from the brownouts, as SSL is enforced with these databases.

Comment: I could probably upgrade and that sounds like the right path long term.  I'd need to figure that out.

Comment: The `pg:upgrade` route where you provision a follower, wait for it to catch up, upgrade it and then switch is probably the best option with the least downtime (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrading-with-pg-upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade was trivial.  Provisioned a new db and copied the data over.  Then promoted the new db.  No problem.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrading-with-pg-copy

Thanks @stefan-magnuson